# ssh-agent error on running: fork_copy fork: Resource Temporarily unavailable

Tags: powershell, ssh-agent

I've been using ssh-agent on my Windows machine for months and months now but after booting up today it's suddenly not working. When I try and Google the errors, Google keeps denying my search for being "unusual traffic" which is too weird but this is what it's returning:

```
ssh-agent C:\users\username\.ssh\id_rsa
0 [main] ssh-agent.exe" 6384 fork_copy: linked dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0xB9E000..0xBA4090,
done 0, windows pid 4592, Win32 error 487
fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

If I run ssh-agent with a bad parameter it then starts up, but isn't connected with my key so it's useless.

I'm going to try rebooting again because there was some Windows updates again last boot (thanks Windows 10(!)) but we'll see...

Reboot appears to have fixed it this time so consider this solved but I'm still very curious as to:

a. Why this might have happened.

b. Why on earth Google would consider this search as "unusual traffic".

Comment: It looks imho like your key is being used by another program. To your _b._ question - No one can know, what exactly you typed in the search field, if you are using any proxy service, are infected, etc.